# Autolayout - why are these constrainsts unsatisfiable?

Tags: swift, autolayout, constraints

So I have built my system of views and constraints, and sometimes I get unsatisfiable constraints error (resolved by breaking constraint). Can anyone tell me why are the following constraints unsatisfiable? (paste it to https://www.wtfautolayout.com/ to make it clearer).

```
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000a94050 UILayoutGuide:0x6000010b47e0'colsep guide 1'.width == UILayoutGuide:0x6000010b4620'etalon'.width   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000a85c70 BASE keyboard.trailing == Keyboard frame.trailing   (active, names: BASE keyboard:0x7fd018e0d9e0, Keyboard frame:0x7fd018e0d7c0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000a85e50 H:|-(0)-[SCIENCE keyboard]   (active, names: SCIENCE keyboard:0x7fd018e1c340, Keyboard frame:0x7fd018e0d7c0, '|':Keyboard frame:0x7fd018e0d7c0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000a81540 H:|-(0)-[Keyboard frame]   (active, names: Keyboard frame:0x7fd018e0d7c0, Main app frame:0x7fd018e06280, '|':Main app frame:0x7fd018e06280 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000a81590 Keyboard frame.trailing == Main app frame.trailing   (active, names: Keyboard frame:0x7fd018e0d7c0, Main app frame:0x7fd018e06280 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000a85fe0 H:[SCIENCE keyboard]-(0)-[BASE keyboard]   (active, names: BASE keyboard:0x7fd018e0d9e0, SCIENCE keyboard:0x7fd018e1c340 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000a860d0 SCIENCE keyboard.width == 0.5*Keyboard frame.width   (active, names: SCIENCE keyboard:0x7fd018e1c340, Keyboard frame:0x7fd018e0d7c0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000a94c80 'etalon width' UILayoutGuide:0x6000010b4620'etalon'.width == 0.03*BASE keyboard.width   (active, names: BASE keyboard:0x7fd018e0d9e0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000a81b80 'nonex leading' Main app frame.leading == UILayoutGuide:0x6000010b78e0'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide'.leading   (active, names: Main app frame:0x7fd018e06280 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000a81bd0 'nonex trailing' Main app frame.trailing == UILayoutGuide:0x6000010b78e0'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide'.trailing   (active, names: Main app frame:0x7fd018e06280 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000af2080 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' Whole window frame.width == 414   (active, names: Whole window frame:0x7fd018d04080 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000a819f0 'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide-left' H:|-(0)-[UILayoutGuide:0x6000010b78e0'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide'](LTR)   (active, names: Whole window frame:0x7fd018d04080, '|':Whole window frame:0x7fd018d04080 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000a81a90 'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide-right' H:[UILayoutGuide:0x6000010b78e0'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide']-(0)-|(LTR)   (active, names: Whole window frame:0x7fd018d04080, '|':Whole window frame:0x7fd018d04080 )>"
)
```

It may seem complicated, but it is not. Basic structure is [Whole window frame] - [UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide] - [Main app frame] - [Keyboard frame] ... each one inside the previous one, taking space from left to right, so all of them should have same width. Then inside [Main app frame] there is [SCIENCE keyboard] and [BASE keyboard] side by side, each taking half of available width. Inside [BASE keyboard] I have [etalon] with width as 0.03 multiple of parent width, and then [colsep guide 1] with the same width as etalon.

During runtime, swift insists that these constraints are unsatisfiable and resolves them by breaking the first one ([colsep guide 1].width = [etalon].width) . But why? The structure is quite simple, I can resolve it by hand just by propagating width of [Whole window frame] down. And breaking of the first constraint changes absolutely nothing.

Comment: Could you provide some screenshots of what you want it to look like and what is happening in xcode?

Comment: Not exactly. Constraints are created by code, and are being activated/deactivated when orientation of phone is changed. After this error is reported, everything looks as it should, but after some more orientation changes layout breaks. I believe there is something more giong on, so I can't exactly show you something and say "this is the result of error". Point is in the error itself. Why it reports constraint collision when there is none? Why is it trying to break constraint that can't change anything?

Answer (score 0):

Got it! It seems a bit like a bug in autolayout to me, but I found the reason of problems. Inside keyboard views I was making a grid of spacers (UILayoutGuides), between which the buttons of keyboard were pinned. Spacers' position was specified by constraint to parent trailing (or bottom for verticals) with multiplier. In order to put it at percentage of parent's width (or height).

Such constraint is not possible to create with anchor api (you can't do anything like `g.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor, multiplier: 0.5)`
). But it is possible to create with basic NSLayoutConstraint, it clearly works in interface builder, and is even recommended in some stackoverflow questions.

I found out that it possibly works, but under some circumstances, it breaks layout in a very weird way. After some activating and deactivating groups of constraints, these constraints started to break in a very weird way, sometimes even silently. So I added some UILayoutGuides taking width (or height) as a multiplier of parent, and then using their trailing (or top) edges to pin centers of my spacers to. Percentage of with or height is possible to do with anchors api, and does not break.

Damn, this was a really nasty one.